# Mysql update menu_order problem

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, mysql

I trying to update menu_order if post_type product not have _thumbnail... 
Tried:

```
UPDATE phiz_posts SET menu_order = 1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM phiz_posts LEFT JOIN phiz_postmeta ON phiz_posts.ID = phiz_postmeta.post_id AND phiz_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' WHERE post_type='product' AND phiz_postmeta.post_id IS NULL)
```

Error: You can't specify target table 'phiz_posts' for update in FROM clause

This sql return the list of product ID without _thumbnail correctly:

```
SELECT ID FROM phiz_posts LEFT JOIN phiz_postmeta ON phiz_posts.ID = phiz_postmeta.post_id AND phiz_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' WHERE post_type='product' AND phiz_postmeta.post_id IS NULL
```

How can change this ?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE phiz_posts p SET menu_order = 1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM phiz_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id') 
AND post_type = 'product' 
AND post_status = 'publish'
```